# Plugin-helpers not found in wazuh-kibana-app

Tags: plugins, kibana, wazuh, kibana-plugin

I have cloned the `Wazuh-Kibana-app` source code from https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app

I have made some changes in the styling. So, i am making build of the app by running `npm run build` but i am getting this error

> Command "plugin-helpers" not found

I think it is because in `package.json` file, it gets like that `"plugin-helpers": "node ../../scripts/plugin_helpers"`  as it is getting out of the directory. So how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Wazuh Kibana plugin uses the [Kibana plugin_helpers](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/tree/7.15/packages/kbn-plugin-helpers) to build a distributable archive of the plugin, information on how to create a Kibana development installation which is capable of building the Wazuh plugin can be found here: https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app/wiki/Develop-new-features

There is also the option of building the Kibana plugin using the wazuh-packages tools as explained here: https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/development/packaging/generate-wazuh-kibana-app.html , however as of right now this only accepts branches from the official Wazuh plugin.

Let me know if you have any more questions!